# Qmetry - How to save return value in to variable & pass it to next step

Tags: web-services, bdd, qaf

Trying to achieve the below scenario in Qmetry.

1. call a function (using step)
2. save the return value into a variable.
3. pass saved value to next function or step.

For instance, I am trying like this

**Scenario steps**:

```
1.generate_token   // this will call a function & return token value
2.store into 'token_value' // save as token_value
3. display variable value '${token_value}'   // here display variable value is custom step.
```

Output showing as null. Not sure on how to pass stored value to next step.

Can any one please let me know why it is not working.

Comment: you need to share implementation of your steps `generate_token` and `display variable value '${token_value}'` step

Comment: @user861594 -  store into {var}  step working.  I see var is of String type. How will it work for return types for ex: ArrayList . Will I be able to save return value i.e ArrayList from previous step & pass it to next step. Is ArrayList is saved to var of String type?  Litle confusion here. Please let me know.

Comment: It can be any object.

Comment: @user861594 . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

if not save in file, you should use static variable to store the value. By the way, not get or save value in properties file with qMetry method in ConfigurationManager.class like getBundle().getPropertyValue(), it not worked in one scenario steps.